# Group rows by value and cell with data

Tags: excel

I have an excel table like this:

```
COLM  COLN   COLO   COLP      
=========================
  A     1    
  A            2
  A                   3
  B     X
  B            Y
  B                   Z
```

And the result table that I want is this one:

```
COLM  COLN   COLO   COLP      
=========================
  A     1     2      3
  B     X     Y      Z
```

Does anyone know some kind of formula to get that result? I appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to do a few steps. Use the formula in the screenshot.

[image]

Afterwards, you'll want to select all in the result table, column F to I, copy/paste values. this will erase the formula.

Afterwards, in column J use this formula.

[image]

Sort by the column furthest to the right, and delete all the rows where the value is true.

Comment: Thank you @Nicho247

Answer (score -1):

Remove duplicates from one column and Delete Blanks from the others. Does not require programming.